# Duplicate Tasks on self reloading gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have set up gulp so that it will reload when the gulpfile is modified. That basic process is working, but for some reason it seems the old tasks are not being terminated properly.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('default', function(){
    var p;

    if(p)
        p.kill();

    p = spawn('gulp', ['watch'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});

gulp.task('watch', ['styles', 'watch-styles', 'watch-gulp']);

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp.src('./**/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

gulp.task('watch-styles', ['styles'], function(){
    gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('watch-gulp', ['styles'], function(){
  gulp.watch('./gulpfile.js', ['default']);
});
```

That is a basic gulpfile that demonstrates the problem. When I tweak that gulpfile to cause it to reload I receive this in the console:

```
[11:21:02] Starting 'default'...
[11:21:02] Finished 'default' after 5.25 ms
[11:21:02] Using gulpfile ~/repo/gulp-reload/gulpfile.js
[11:21:02] Starting 'styles'...
[11:21:02] Finished 'styles' after 34 ms
[11:21:02] Starting 'watch-styles'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'watch-styles' after 669 ms
[11:21:03] Starting 'watch-gulp'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'watch-gulp' after 1.83 ms
[11:21:03] Starting 'watch'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'watch' after 2.92 μs
```

Then modifying a less file within the directory gives this output

```
[11:21:24] Starting 'styles'...
[11:21:24] Finished 'styles' after 8.95 ms
[11:21:24] Starting 'styles'...
[11:21:24] Finished 'styles' after 2.92 ms
```

Each subsequent restart seems to lead to an additional call to styles, as if the old watchers are still there.

I created a small [repo on Github](https://github.com/mudetroit/gulp-self-reload-problem) with this example project as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this task:

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    var p;

    if(p)
        p.kill();

    p = spawn('gulp', ['watch'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

p is never defined, because you always create a new variable when you call that function. Also, you don't have a pointer to your own process which you want to kill. A safer way would be to end all the other watchers by hand:

```
gulp.task('watch-styles', ['styles'], function(){
    var watcher = gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['styles']);
    watchers.push(watcher);
});

gulp.task('watch-gulp', ['styles'], function(){
    var watcher = gulp.watch('./gulpfile.js', ['default']);
    watchers.push(watcher);
    watcher.on('change', function(){
        watchers.forEach(function(el){
            el.end();
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: I think you are likely correct in terms of the reason, the reference to the process. I am not a big fan of managing a collection of watchers though. What did work was moving the watching of the gulpfile into the defailt task and wrapping the spawning portion in a function.